# split on final space in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a `name` variable that has I can usually to expect to take the form of

`John Smith`

though it cannot be validated, and sometimes it may appear as

`John  Smith`

or

`John Jay Smith`

I want to ultimately end up with two variables, `firstName` and `lastName` with a split on the final space, so I would end up with

`John Jay` & `Smith`

`John` & `Smith`

`John` & `Smith`

What's the best way to accomplish this split on a final space?

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [string.lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [string.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

It wont be as convenient as a split along some character, but you can accomplish it in 3 statements regardless, (1) finding the index of the last space, (2) getting the part before that and (3) getting the part after that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
[firstname..., lastname] = "John Jay Smith".split(/ +/)
firstname = firstname.join(" ")
console.log firstname
console.log lastname
```

Comment: That character class is unnecessary, just use `/ +/`

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to accomplish this split on a final space?

The last space (or spaces) can be defined using a negative look-ahead, so just split on that:

```
[first, last] = "John Jay Smith".split(/\s+(?!.+ )/)
```

Or, regexp can pull it apart for you easily:

```
[, first, last] = "John Jay Smith".match(/^(.*)\s+(\S+)$/)
```